# issue with launching an application with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I am on Windows 11 Home. I have created a shortcut CTRL+ALT+A in the properties to start Ableton Live. I have created a project template that loads automatically when Ableton starts. The template consists Sonarworks plugin on the master track. The problem occurs when I use the shortcut to launch Ableton. I get a warning that Sonarworks couldn't be found and was not loaded. But when I launch Ableton with a mouse double click the application loads the template properly without any warnings. But then when I give Admin Rights to the app in Properties I can launch the app with a shortcut properly as well.

How does the shortcut change the process of launching the apps?